# install ef 5 on server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, deployment

I develop a web application on Microsoft .Net 4 and Entity Framework 5.  When I upload the project on my web farm it doesn't work.  I believe that Entity Framework is not installed on my web farm.  So I contacted my host to support this particular issue.

They said:

> Send us a download and installation instructions, with any
>   requirements to install Entity Framework.

Except we utilize a link from directly within Visual Studio through Nuget.

How do you load the proper deployment information onto a server, since you can't directly deploy with Nuget since they don't have Visual Studio installed?

Server Information:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 64 Bit
- [Nuget link I used to install Entity Framework.](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0)

If possible please guide me or reference a place where I can solve this deployment issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: In your application your deployment package should include the required assemblies to generate correctly.

Comment: wow i must upload that package folder on my host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to successfully launch your project on a deployment server you should ensure that your application has a Deployment Package to be installed on the server.

[Deployment Considerations can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518967.aspx):

You have a lot of things you need to consider, but Entity Framework does have a lot of choices and flexibility.  Some of your choices:

- Click Once Security and Deployment
- Windows Installer Deployment

> What Is a ClickOnce Application?
>
> A ClickOnce application is any Windows Presentation Foundation
> (.xbap), Windows Forms (.exe), console application (.exe), or Office
> solution (.dll) published using ClickOnce technology. You can publish
> a ClickOnce application in three different ways: from a Web page, from
> a network file share, or from media such as a CD-ROM. A ClickOnce
> application can be installed on an end user's computer and run locally
> even when the computer is offline, or it can be run in an online-only
> mode without permanently installing anything on the end user's
> computer. For more information, see Choosing a ClickOnce Deployment
> Strategy.
>
> ClickOnce applications can be self-updating; they can check for newer
> versions as they become available and automatically replace any
> updated files. The developer can specify the update behavior; a
> network administrator can also control update strategies, for example,
> marking an update as mandatory. Updates can also be rolled back to an
> earlier version by the end user or by an administrator. For more
> information, see Choosing a ClickOnce Update Strategy.
>
> Because ClickOnce applications are isolated, installing or running a
> ClickOnce application cannot break existing applications. ClickOnce
> applications are self-contained; each ClickOnce application is
> installed to and run from a secure per-user, per-application cache.
> ClickOnce applications run in the Internet or Intranet security zones.
> If necessary, the application can request elevated security
> permissions. For more information, see Securing ClickOnce
> Applications.
>
> How does a Windows Installer Deployment work?
>
> Windows Installer
> deployment enables you to create installer packages to be distributed
> to users; the user runs the setup file and steps through a wizard to
> install the application. This is accomplished by adding a Setup
> project to your solution. When built, the project creates a setup file
> that you distribute to users; the user runs the setup file and steps
> through a wizard to install the application.

That is a brief description of a few ways, you can find [examples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191532.aspx): Once you actually have your host load your deployment package it should run without any issues.  Hopefully this points you in the correct direction.